# JMeter is adding additional character to auth token

Tags: jmeter, authorization, access-token

I am using JMeter 3.1.

I am sending the following path

```
core/DocumentRenderer/api/cmbs/54ad43a8cbda7177fc83b2c5?Authorization=${authentication}
```

I am receiving back

```
core/DocumentRenderer/api/cmbs/54ad43a8cbda7177fc83b2c5?Authorization=%20A3BB6A2F90D13D76E99483509DE3F864BB51C8424ACA5792D651F43C2B20A65C42ACEAB0DC03493060EF59E2654C482AC38333AB4BFBAAB2E073809CE8E97E4C7E62B02D766ABF3344818D13A981D40C447AFC3458AAE54E92705D20D0C49D7A8565B72C227A2663C3944931F4B747840E8FE01B599A2A5C205E39973A8A98DDD80BE61E46C8E3222334CF4C1A512FADED5EF5C9A493333058BE70A04DA835FA045AF474BFDFBD84878F53182E3B6726
```

with `%20` as an additional character.

I also tried to add authorization as parameter

```
Authorization=${authentication}
```

but then it adds or + if I use Encoded=Yes or space if Encoded unchecked.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't add anything, most probably your [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) which extracts the token value is obtaining an extra space so your `${authentication}` variable basically has a space in the beginning, you can double check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination. Amend your Post-Processor logic so it won't include the space into the variable.

Another option is using i.e. [__javaScript()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function to remove spaces from the `{authentication}` variable itself like:

```
core/DocumentRenderer/api/cmbs/54ad43a8cbda7177fc83b2c5?Authorization=${__javaScript("${authentication}".replace(/ /g\,''),)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JavaScript Remove White Space]